# Loading data from multiple db to another server using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have used SSIS package to move table columns and data from one database to another database.

SERVER A, Database A, Table A

SERVER B, Database B, Table B (but only with selected columns from Table A)

I have used Data flow task with OLEDB source and OLEDB destinations. Derived columns as well to create new date columns in Table B in SERVER B. I need to do this automatically to load 50 databases Table A from SERVER A to Table B (with selected columns from Table A) into SERVER B using SQL Job. 
Please can anyone suggest me how to nake database load as a loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Biml as column information....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show you how to grab ALL the columns from the 50 tables of DatabaseA and load them into DatabaseB using SSIS. That package will look something like this.

[image]

I'll explain the logic flow.

The first Execute SQL task is going to get a list of tables from the Information Schema.

```
TABLE_SCHEMA|TABLE_NAME
MySchemaA   |MyTableA1
MySchemaA   |MyTableA2
```

We're going to take that list and save it as a `ResultSet` variable.  Once saved, we can loop over the `ResultSet` using a Foreach Loop ADO Enumerator task.  For each loop we're going to map values from one row into the `TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TABLE_NAME` SSIS variables.  Then, we will use those values in dynamic SQL statement. The second Execute SQL task is getting it's command from the `SQLStatement` variable.  We've set that variable by the following Expression ...

`"SELECT * INTO DatabaseB." + @[User::TABLE_SCHEMA] + "." + @[User::TABLE_NAME] +"  FROM DatabaseA."+ @[User::TABLE_SCHEMA] + "." + @[User::TABLE_NAME]`

So for each loop, the schema and table name is injected into the SQL statement, and the table is SELECT * INTO a destination table of the same name.

Look [here](https://thesqldev.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/iterate-over-databases-using-ssis-part-1/) and [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/) for more detailed examples about how to use the Foreach Loop ADO enumerator to map the variables.

Now...

I did read that you wanted

> with selected columns from Table A

If you're lucky enough to need the exact same columnset from each of your 50 tables in DatabaseA then, just change the `*` in the query above to `[ColumnA],[ColumnB],[ColumnC]`.  If you happen to need a different columnset for each table, well... that may be problematic. You'd need to create a list of `TABLE_NAME | ColumnSet` and integrate that into your looping... and well.. thats starting to sound like a lot of work!  You could probably do the 50 by hand before you could code it.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I have these below databases. how do I need to add only these Database list into for loop? 
please suggest me

Comment: name create_date
Sales_backup_201201312300 03/10/2016 09:21
Sales_backup_201202292300 03/10/2016 09:26
Sales_backup_201203312300 03/10/2016 09:32
Sales_backup_201204302300 03/10/2016 09:38
Sales_backup_201205312300 03/10/2016 09:44
Sales_backup_201206302300 05/10/2016 12:01
Sales_backup_201207312300 03/10/2016 12:14
Sales_backup_201208312300 03/10/2016 12:25
Sales_backup_201209302300 03/10/2016 12:37
Sales_backup_201210312300 03/10/2016 13:17
Sales_backup_201211302300 03/10/2016 13:48
Sales_backup_201212312300 03/10/2016 14:45

Comment: Sales_backup_201301151850 05/10/2016 10:34
Sales_backup_201302021850 05/10/2016 11:36
Sales_backup_201303011850 05/10/2016 12:06
Sales_backup_201304161850 05/10/2016 12:44
Sales_backup_201305161850 06/10/2016 11:09
Sales_backup_201306141850 05/10/2016 13:14
Sales_backup_201307151850 05/10/2016 13:21
Sales_backup_201308141850 05/10/2016 13:28
Sales_backup_201309131850 05/10/2016 13:36
Sales_backup_201310141850 05/10/2016 13:44
Sales_backup_201311151850 05/10/2016 13:51
Sales_backup_201312311850 06/10/2016 09:25

Comment: Sales_backup_201401301850 30/09/2016 14:26
Sales_backup_201402271850 29/09/2016 09:33
Sales_backup_201403311850 30/09/2016 14:36
Sales_backup_201404291850 28/09/2016 13:03
Sales_backup_201405311850 28/09/2016 13:31
Sales_backup_201406301850 29/09/2016 09:46
Sales_backup_201407301850 29/09/2016 10:11
Sales_backup_201408301850 29/09/2016 10:40
Sales_backup_201409301850 27/09/2016 12:30
Sales_backup_201410311850 30/09/2016 14:52
Sales_backup_201411311850 06/10/2016 10:53
Sales_backup_201412311850 23/09/2016 13:20

Comment: Sales_backup_2015_05_31_230001_7137975 09/09/2016 09:23
Sales_backup_2015_06_30_203001_8647044 08/09/2016 14:58
Sales_backup_2015_07_31_203001_8009608 09/09/2016 09:40
Sales_backup_2015_08_31_203002_1718153 09/09/2016 09:17
Sales_backup_2015_09_30_203001_6301490 09/09/2016 10:11
Sales_backup_2015_10_31_203003_4130018 09/09/2016 10:35
Sales_backup_2015_11_30_203001_8901986 13/09/2016 10:26
Sales_backup_2015_12_31_203001_8001013 13/09/2016 11:57
Sales_backup_201501311850 23/09/2016 13:38
Sales_backup_201502282300 23/09/2016 13:58
Sales_backup_201503312300 23/09/2016 14:22

Comment: Sales_backup_201504302300 23/09/2016 16:18
Sales_backup_2016_01_31_203001_6395239 15/09/2016 11:20

Comment: need to add sorted by name? not on create_date

Answer (score 0):

This means that the query is predictable as well as the destination table names.

You can make a loop through the tables you need either by putting their names in a table or getting them from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Inside this loop container, you can construct the source queries from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` then make the source component in the `Data Flow` use expression to use your query.

Comment: after adding the database names to a table how do I need to get those databases into for loop or for each loop container? please advice