# Issue loading-data-from-multiple-db-to-another-server-using-ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

I am facing issue in loading-data-from-multiple-db-to-another-server-using-ssis
I have referred the below link
[Loading data from multiple db to another server using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747452/loading-data-from-multiple-db-to-another-server-using-ssis?answertab=oldest#tab-top) 

SSIS Package FLow :
[image: SSIS Package Flow]
[image: SSIS Package Flow]
[image: SSIS Package Flow]
Unfortunately i am getting the error in "Execute SQL Task" as below:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result
>   bindings returned for the ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".

Appreciate if you could help me with the solutions.
Thanks

Comment: In Result Set, you need to specify variable of `object type`(ResultSet in your case) and `result name` as 0. Did you do that ?

Comment: Also, you do not require parameter settings because the query is an expression.  Parameters would be used if you had a statement that uses placeholder syntax like `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = ?` WHERE "?" maps to parameter name "0"

Comment: yes i have done as suggested by you .

Comment: PrabhatG are you asking me to add the resultset in Execute SQL Task..if so i did it and got the below error: [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query ""SELECT * INTO ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS" + @[User::..." failed with the following error: "Parameter name is unrecognized.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I removed the parameter as suggested and got the below error:[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query ""SELECT * INTO ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS" + @[User::..." failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near '+'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: Hold on..I will guide you through answer.

Comment: Make sure the SQLStatement variable has EvaluateAsExpression set to true

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz yes...it has been set to yes.

Comment: @Julie : I could do this through google hangout but it might violate SO rules. Lets stick to the question-answer medium and keep team viewer as last resort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, to solve your issue

**1.** Evaluate your SQL Statement. For instance :
[image: img1]

**2.** Once your variable query is evaluating, move to `Execute SQL Task`. It should look like this:

[image: img2]

**3.** Next the resultSet should look like this (object_variable is of `object` type)

[image: img3]

**Why** are we not using anything in parameter mapping ?

Answer: If we had a SQL query like `Select col1, col2 from table1 where col3 = ?`, Then we would be replacing `?` with either a parameter or a variable.

In your case, delete everything inside parameter mapping.

**Updated** : Also, since you're query is `Select * into tbl2 from tbl1`, ResultSet property should be None instead of any other thing.

Comment: I am using the variables as i am dynamically replacing the table and schema name from the previous execute sql task..

Comment: @Julie : I have used variable inside variable too. `sqlQuery` has `TableName` variable. Our scenario is same, isn't it ? Put some random value in your variables and verify the step1 from above please ? Can you see proper "evaluated result" ?

Comment: The dynamic query "SELECT * INTO ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS.dbo"  + "." + @[User::Table_Name]  +"  FROM  AdventureWorks2014."+ @[User::Table_Schema] + "." +  @[User::Table_Name]" is being properly replaced with "SELECT * INTO ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS.dbo.ScrapReason  FROM  AdventureWorks2014.Production.ScrapReason" as expected..

Comment: I am getting the below error : [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "SELECT * INTO ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS.dbo.ScrapRea..." failed with the following error: "Parameter name is unrecognized.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: @Julie : a very minor mistake we are doing. Set `ResultSet` to None instead of Full Result Set and run. :)

Comment: @Julie : If it helped, kindly upvote and mark it as answer to show appreciation  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Execute SQL Tasks

1, First Execute SQL Task, get list of tables and schema, it expects a Full Result set and map it to a object type variable.

2, Foreach loop container,  ADO Enumerator, ADO source is the object type variable. Variable Mappings to 2 string type variables, 1 is for table name and 1 is for schema name.

3. Second Execute SQL Task, it has no Full Result set, no parameter mapping. Because table name/schema name changes are taken care of by Foreach loop container.